# Problem creating/calling a DLL

Tags: c, delphi, dll, compilation, inno-setup

I'm trying to create a DLL that will later be used in Inno Setup.
I managed to create a DLL using Pelles as an IDE, with the following code:

```
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport) int sumT(){
   return 2;
}
```

Then I call map the DLL to a function in Inno Setup, using the following Delphi code:

```
function Hellow() : Integer ;
external 'sumT@files:yyy.dll stdcall';
```

It works as expected, returning 2. I can also call it from rundll32.exe - if I add a MsgBox in the DLL, it will appear, proving that everything works as expected.

Now the problem starts when I try to pass a value to the DLL, like that - for example:

```
#include <windows.h>

__declspec(dllexport) int sumT(int sumTah){
   return sumTah;
}
```

It stops working!
In Inno Setup, I gives me the message:

> "Runtime Error (at -1:0)"

And if I try rundll32.exe, I get:

> Error in yyy.dll
>
> Missing entry:sumT

I'm not going to paste the Delphi code here, because I virtually tried everything, same thing with the C code, I tried using __stdcall instead, declaring the argument as INT, UINT... and other things I forgot.

I also looked up the MSDN, but could not find anything pertaining to this particular problem.

So, can anyone help?

Thanks

EDIT: I am compiling in C, so no need for "extern".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exported name probably doesn't match what you think it looks like.  Use dumpbin.exe /exports on the DLL to see the actual exported name.  Use extern "C" to suppress name mangling.

Also, you have to declare this function __stdcall, that's what your Delphi declaration said.  The default is __cdecl.  That will fail when you start passing arguments.

Comment: Thanks for the Tip about using dumpbin.exe
It turns out the function is exported as "_sumT@4"
I found an option in the compiler that says "Undecorate Exported stdcall functions" (In Project options -> Compiler). That should do it. BTW __stdcall doesnt seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile with a C++ compiler, the function name gets mangled so that it contains data about the arguments. The solution is to do something like:

`extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) int myfn();`

and then reference it as _myfn. The `extern "C"` tells the compiler to not mangle the function name. This does not work with templated functions, classes or overloaded functions.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot to mention that I am already compiling in C, so no need for "extern" (AFAIK). But the function does get exported as _sumT@4, so you were right about the underscore. I fixed that by setting a compiler option ("Undecorate Exported stdcall functions").

Comment: stdcall functions add the number of bytes that the stack is taking up to the end (the @4 in your case, here); leaving them undecorated may cause stack corruption issues. You probably want to mark it with the cdecl calling convention, which will always leave the call as `_sumT`.

Answer (score 1):

__declspec(dllexport) int sumT(int **sumThah**){
   return **sumTah**;

looks like a typo or your error....